# Оптимизация проверки в excel

Tags: excel, vba

Спасибо за Вашу помощь, создан макрос для excel, но теперь встал вопрос оптимизации работы данного макроса. Для 130 записей работает секунд 20, при этом ограничения наложено всего на примерно 10 столбцов. Должно быть более ста столбцов и строк несколько тысяч. Это будет тормозить. Каким образом можно произвести эту оптимизацию?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range) Dim objCell As Range
    If Target.Row = 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Not Application.Intersect(Range("A:CY"), Target) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        For Each objCell In Target
            With objCell
                    If Len(.Value) > 0 Then
                    Select Case .Column
                    Case 1, 2
                        If TypeName(.Value) = "String" Then
                            .Value = Left(.Value, 100)
                        Else
                            .Value = .Value
                        End If
                    Case 3, 4
                        If TypeName(.Value) = "String" Then
                            .Value = Left(.Value, 5)
                        Else
                            .Value = .Value
                        End If
                     Case 5, 6
                        If .Value <> 0 And .Value <> 1 Then .Value = ""
                     Case 7, 8
                        .Value = Replace(.Value, ";", "")
                     Case 9, 10
                        If Not IsNumeric(.Value) Then .ClearContents
                    End Select
                End If
            End With
        Next objCell
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If End Sub
```

Спасибо.

Comment: `Application.ScreenUpdating = False`, `Application.ScreenUpdating = True`?

Comment: 1. Неправильно: по каждому чиху создавать тему. вернее, плодить вопросы по одному коду===2. Вы создаете темы на форумах. получаете решение, но не отписываетесь и заходите с другими вопросами - никакого желания помогать.

Comment: В том форуме я вышел, никак не могу войти. Извините сколько пытался - безуспешно. Думаю меня забанили, хотя вродебы ничего не нарушал.

Comment: комментарий от @vikttur относится к этому форуму. Он ответил уже на 3 Ваших вопроса, Вы вроде пользуетесь его решениями, т.е. они Вам помогли. Но при этом ни один из ответов на заданные вопросы Вы не отметили как правильный.

Comment: Эдуард, хоть Ваше замечание и правильное, но п.2 комментария - о другом ресурсе. Проявить обычное уважение, отписавшись в теме, считается хорошим тоном.

Comment: 1 отметил, как правильный

Comment: как отметить то, что правильный - кнопки не вижу такой?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Отключать/включать обновление экрана:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = false
...
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Если на листе есть формулы, тем более если они летучие (пересчитываются при любом изменении на листе) - отключать/включать автовычисления:

```
Application.Calculation = xlManual
...
Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
```

Если препредполагается обработка больших диапазонов данных, в коде использовать массивы, обращение к листу минимизировать - работа с объектами медленная.

Возможно, лучше отказаться от использования событий листа и запускать макрос принудительно (кнопкой, сочетанием клавиш...).

При сложных обработках и если эти обработки для разных диапазонов различаются, имеет смысл каждый диапазон обрабатывать отдельной процедурой, объединив их вызов одним макросом. Этот пункт - больше для удобства работы с кодом в будущем.

Comment: Спасибо. "Буду копать"

Comment: Некоторое замечание: почему то данный макрос на второй строке работает, но при последующих изменениях - не работает как надо, хотя вроде должен всю время правильно - работать(по - коду оценивая)

Comment: Что там в Вашей строке и какие диапазоны изменяете - неведомо. Возможно, сбой и события остались отключенными. Гадать? Здесь - об оптимизации вычислений на больших объемах, а не об ошибках